# Django - Error al recuperar un dato con filter

Tags: django, django-models

Necesito tomar un dato pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

Error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Código:

```
from .models import Incidencia

def dato(request):
    incidencias = Incidencia.objects.filter(id='1')
    dato=incidencias.observaciones
```

Comment: Adjunta todo el error, por favor.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de los objetos Incidencia? ¿es id de tipo cadena o numérico?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro replique el problema, y al parecer funciona sin ningún error pasar el `id` de tipo cadena a pesar de que un `id` sea numérico, sospecho que el error no tiene que ver con el `.filter()`, creo que el error es por algo así: `<QuerySet>.id`, a lo mejor se confundió y utilizo el método `.filter()` en ves del método `.get()`, ya que esta filtrando por `id`, y observando de nuevo el código `dato=incidencias.observaciones`, debería dar error, ya que el método `.filter()` retorna un QuerySet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema que describes aparece por que la consulta **"Incidencia.objects.filter(id='1')"** devuelve como respuesta un QuerySet, que es conjunto de valores, como una lista pero con mas opciones.
Debido a esto si quiere acceder al atributo **"observaciones"** debes hacerlo sobre algún elemento del QuerySet, por ejemplo:

```
incidencias = Incidencia.objects.filter(id='1')
dato = incidencias.first().observaciones
```

Si desea que te entregue todas las observaciones de las incidencia deberías usar esto:

```
incidencias = Incidencia.objects.filter(id='1')
observaciones = incidencias.values_list('id', 'observaciones')
```

**observaciones** contendrá como resultado una tupla que dentro tendrá tuplas, algo así:

```
observaciones = ((1, 'observaciones 1'), (2, 'observaciones 2'), (3, 'observaciones 3'))
```

de igual forma puedes obtener una tupla con diccionarios como repuesta sustituyendo **values_list** por **values** o una lista, utilizando la propiedad de **flat=True** en **values_list**, pero esta opción solo es aplicable cuando quieres obtener un solo campo del modelo:

```
observaciones = list(set(incidencias.values_list('observaciones', flat=True)))
```

**observaciones** contendrá como resultado una **lista** (list) donde se han eliminado los repetidos (set), quedando como resultado:

```
observaciones = ['observaciones 1', 'observaciones 2', 'observaciones 3']
```

Espero haber respondido tu pregunta, saludos.